# Form submission, just can't stop refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

So I am very new to this stuff and i have a specific problem I just can't fix. I have searched all over, and I have tried loads of solutions to no avail. I'm sure I'm missing something or have something in the wrong order but I just need some guidance.

I have a simple form in my website and I can't stop it refreshing the page on submit. There's some php validating happening also.

Here's a link to the website: [www.nathanchapmanphotography.co.uk](http://www.nathanchapmanphotography.co.uk)

Any help would be massively appreciated.

```js
$("form").submit(function() {

  var error = "";
  var success = "";
  var fail = "";

  if ($("#name").val() == "") {
    error += "name required<br>";
  }

  if ($("#email").val() == "") {
    error += "email required<br>";
  }

  if ($("#message").val() == "") {
    error += "message required<br>";
  }
  
  if (error != "") {
    $("#error").html(error);
    $("#success").html(success);
    $("#fail").html(fail);
    return false;
  } 
  else {
    sendContactForm();
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
  <p class="form-p">name:
    <input class="input" type="text" id="name" name="name">
  </p>
  <p class="form-p">email:
    <input class="input" type="email" id="email" name="email">
  </p>
  <p class="form-p">message:
    <br/>
    <textarea id="message" cols="40" rows="7" name="message"></textarea>
  </p>
  <button type="submit" id="submit">submit</button>
  <div id="error">
    <? echo $error; ?>
  </div>
  <div id="success">
    <? echo $success; ?>
  </div>
  <div id="fail">
    <? echo $fail; ?>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to prevent the default action of the submit event:

```
$("form").submit(function(event) { // capture the function's event here
    event.preventDefault(); // use the captured event here
    // rest of your code...
```

---

EDIT: from the OP's website after the change -

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for replying, I have tried having that in there previously and have added it again now but this change causes the form to not submit at all. Any ideas? Once again if you visit the website I linked to's source you'll see all the js at the bottom.

Comment: Where is the form supposed to submit to? It looks like it should submit to the same page. We don't generally make it a habit to visit unknown websites unless we're just absolutely not able to solve the problem.

Comment: As a side note, be aware that using `event` as the parameter name will override the browsers default event object named `event` and the browser `event` object and the event object passed as parameter by jQuery do differ.

Comment: No problem, the form at the moment, refreshes the whole page and sends an email via php to me and posts a success report in a div by the form when you scroll back down. What I would like is no refresh, so you click submit and it posts the data to php, displays the success without dragging the user back to the top of the page, pre loading screen etc.

Comment: Then what I have given you should work unless there are other problems in the code we cannot see. I just ran a quick test with no issues at all.

Comment: I must have other issues then, as when I have added your section the submit button is allowing the validation to run and display errors but not submitting the data when there are no errors.

Comment: Ok I think I found the problem, your part is right and runs through the validation but in my else statement there is nothing sending the data to my php. do you know a way i can post without submiting the form?

Comment: You could use AJAX to post the data to the PHP script.

Comment: so would I just add that to my else condition? I don't suppose you can whip up an example for me? I've never used it.

Comment: [Here is an example](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you are looking for,..however,

If `sendContactForm` does the posting of the form data and you just don't want the submit to happen automatically you can make the button of type `button` and bind to it for the validation.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function sendContactForm(){
    console.log('sendContactForm');
  };
  
  $('#submit').on('click', function() {
    var error = "";
    var success = "";
    var fail = "";

    if ($("#name").val() === "") {

      error += "name required<br>";
    }

    if ($("#email").val() === "") {

      error += "email required<br>";
    }

    if ($("#message").val() === "") {

      error += "message required<br>";
    }

    if (error !== "") {

      $("#error").html(error);
      $("#success").html(success);
      $("#fail").html(fail);

    } else {
      sendContactForm();
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
  <p class="form-p">name:
    <input class="input" type="text" id="name" name="name">
  </p>
  <p class="form-p">email:
    <input class="input" type="email" id="email" name="email">
  </p>
  <p class="form-p">message:
    <br/>
    <textarea id="message" cols="40" rows="7" name="message"></textarea>
  </p>
  <button type="button" id="submit">submit</button>
  <div id="error">
    <? echo $error; ?>
  </div>
  <div id="success">
    <? echo $success; ?>
  </div>
  <div id="fail">
    <? echo $fail; ?>
  </div>
</form>
```

---

or,..if you want to only have more control over the submit itself without the page refreshing, you can use ajax. Similar to this:

```
var $form = $("form");

$.ajax({
    data: $form.serialize(),
    url: $form[0].action,
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        sendContactForm();
    }
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function postData() {
    var $form = $("form");

    $.ajax({
      data: $form.serialize(),
      url: $form[0].action,
      type: 'post',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        sendContactForm();
      }
    });
  }

  function sendContactForm() {
    console.log('sendContactForm');
  }

  $('#submit').on('click', function() {
    var error = "";
    var success = "";
    var fail = "";

    if ($("#name").val() === "") {

      error += "name required<br>";
    }

    if ($("#email").val() === "") {

      error += "email required<br>";
    }

    if ($("#message").val() === "") {

      error += "message required<br>";
    }

    if (error !== "") {

      $("#error").html(error);
      $("#success").html(success);
      $("#fail").html(fail);

    } else {
      postData();
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="http://yourtageturl">
  <p class="form-p">name:
    <input class="input" type="text" id="name" name="name">
  </p>
  <p class="form-p">email:
    <input class="input" type="email" id="email" name="email">
  </p>
  <p class="form-p">message:
    <br/>
    <textarea id="message" cols="40" rows="7" name="message"></textarea>
  </p>
  <button type="button" id="submit">submit</button>
  <div id="error">
    <? echo $error; ?>
  </div>
  <div id="success">
    <? echo $success; ?>
  </div>
  <div id="fail">
    <? echo $fail; ?>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi thanks very much, I am not having much luck, I wonder if the sendcontactform() is not sending to my php, could there be a communication issue?  What I am looking for is basically a submit that sends the form info to my php and doesn't refresh the page. Sorry i know it's a bit unclear, I'm very inexperienced.

Comment: I don't know what you are doing inside `sendcontactform()` but calling a `$('form').submit` anywhere will also trigger the submit and refresh the page. Assuming it is not submitting any forms in there, changing the button type to `button` will stop automatically submitting the form and should stop any page refresh but you then need to manually post the data. The ajax variance will not refresh the page either, it will simply post the data of your form to the form's target (action). You can use the `ajax` `success/complete/error`

Comment: ok, i've rolled the code back on my website to what I originally had (it was getting a little muddled) I think the problem is that function isn't doing anything. in my original snipet, what can i replace sendContactForm(); with to post the data for my php. i will use the button strategy to stop the refresh.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to sort it using both your suggestions, thanks so much. The issue was that the function I found online to send the data actually wasn't doing anything. I have it running perfectly now, no server side validation but that's for another day. If your interested, here's the revised code.

```js
$("form").submit(function(e) {

e.preventDefault();

var error = "";
var success = "Thank you for your message!<br/>I'll get back to you shortly."
var url = "index.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.

    if ($("#name").val() == "") {
    
    error += "name required<br>";
}

if ($("#email").val() == "") {
    
    error += "email required<br>";
}

if ($("#message").val() == "") {
    
    error += "message required<br>";
}

if (error != "") {
    
    $("#error").html(error);
    //alert("We need your" + error + "please!" );
    
} 
else {
    
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: url,
       data: $("form").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
       success: function(data)
       {
           $("#success").html(success);
           $("#error").html(error);
       }
     });
}

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
  <p class="form-p">name:
    <input class="input" type="text" id="name" name="name">
  </p>
  <p class="form-p">email:
    <input class="input" type="email" id="email" name="email">
  </p>
  <p class="form-p">message:
    <br/>
    <textarea id="message" cols="40" rows="7" name="message"></textarea>
  </p>
  <button type="submit" id="submit">submit</button>
  <div id="error">
    <? echo $error; ?>
  </div>
  <div id="success">
    <? echo $success; ?>
  </div>
  <div id="fail">
    <? echo $fail; ?>
  </div>
</form>
```